# 99 in AES s-box, where it came from?

Tags: aes, s-boxes

The multiplicative inverse in AES s-box is transformed using the following affine transformation:

$s = b \oplus (b \lll 1) \oplus (b \lll 2) \oplus (b \lll 3) \oplus (b \lll 4) \oplus 99_{10}$

Where did the number 99 come from? For what purpose is it there?

I'm asking, because I'm trying to generalize it in $GF(2^{128})$. So I would like to find a similar number if we would operating in $GF(2^{128})$.

Comment: [crypto.stackexchange.com question #40132](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40132/)

Comment: @j.p. yes, I think it is clear enough. Thanks!